# How to Link the Image URL in fire base storage to database under specific user in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am new on fire base. I am working on an Application. I have uploaded the profile image and user data to fire base.But now i a confused how to related the profile pictures to specific user. For example Name= Hussain , Contact=########### and the profile image in storage is 112313.jpg. Another user is name=Ali, contact=######## and profile image=1323.jpg. 
So, the question is how i can get the image of hussain under hussain detail, and liaqat's image under liaqat detail.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on your application, you should probably create a separate node called Users and save in there all their profile information including their profile picture which would point to the storage uri.

Then you can use the example  @Nagaraj N provided below to save/update the url on their profile.

Answer (score 1):

Once You have uploaded your profile image to [firebase cloud storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files), you can get the URL of that. Then, You can update your profile image URL to that particular users details in Real time database. Please look at the code below,

```
    // File or Blob
    file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/mountains.jpg"));

    // Create the file metadata
    metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
            .setContentType("image/jpeg")
            .build();

    // Upload file and metadata to the path 'images/mountains.jpg'
    uploadTask = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(file, metadata);

    // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // Handle successful uploads on complete
            Uri downloadUrl=taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference('users').child('hussain_UID')
    .child('photoURL')
    .set(downloadUrl.toString());

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps your query.

Comment: well explained but i need more explanation as i am new.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what that last FirebaseDatabase call is doing?